# I want to parse an online document using C# 4.0 and get the name, address, phone and email?

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I want to parse it and then extract the top portion and export those portions to Excel with headings, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the format of the document you're reading? Is that an Excel file, too?

Comment: each of those are complex types that require their own specialized reader. You can usually find C#/.Net readers of each of those types available as free or commercial libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. parse the file (no way to help you here based on your explanation)
2. create an output XML file.
3. write the values as an XML stream with proper Excel tags.

Comment: I want to parse either any type of standard used document like Word, HTML, PDF, etc...